# DC-DC 12V to 3.3V 5V 12V power module multi output voltage converter not getting proper voltage if all loads are connected at same time

Tags: voltage, buck

I am using the multi voltage output module as shown in the image below . Also links attached for product page. It provides 3 output i.e. 3.3V, 5V and input as provided.

I am trying to use it to power three loads at the same time. That's one CPU fan (12V), a wireless keyboard (3V) and a laptop cooling pad (5V.)  I am providing 12V 2A input power to it using an adapter.

The CPU fan is running fine and the keyboard is running fine as well, but as soon as I connect the laptop cooling pad, the voltage drops to almost zero for the keyboard (i.e. 3.3V output point.) The laptop cooling pad isn't running at full potential, either.

I don't have much idea about electronics, I just like to try things like these. Could you guys help me in identifying what the issue is, or is it designed to work that way?

[image]

- [Regulator board source 1.](https://www.techtonics.in/dc-dc-12v-to-3-3v-5v-12v-power-module-multi-output-voltage-conversion)
- [Regulator board source 2.](https://www.electronicscomp.com/dc-dc-12v-to-3.3v-5v-12v-power-module-multi-output-voltage-conversion?gclid=CjwKCAiA3pugBhAwEiwAWFzwddES_e9dAYGszXNGDvozk_2VfGCbwaqU54mzU4IWl-6CzjkOyGWFWhoCT3cQAvD_BwE)

**EDIT:**

Power drawn on different loads is

CPU fan: 420mA at 12V, 320mA at 9V

laptop cooling pad: 620mA at 5V

Wireless keyboard: 35mA max at 3V

[image]

[Laptop cooling pad I am using.](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B074C8C6F4/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

Power adapter I am using:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a data sheet link or schematic for the product in the photograph. Please provide a data sheet link for the cooler. Please provide details of the 12 volt supply that feeds the barrel jack.

Comment: have you tried running the cooling pad by itself?

Comment: @jsotola, Yes, currently I am running the cooling pad using a mobile phone adapter which provides 5V and is running absolutely fine.

Comment: @Andyaka, I don't have any data sheets for these. But I have updated the question with the links and pics of the products I am using i.e. Power module, laptop cooling pad and Power adapter. This power adapter is 9V 2A. Even if I use 12V 2A, still the problem I mentioned arises.

Comment: The power supply is 0.8A out of 3.3 and the 5V. 12V is directly tied to the 12V input. So what are you supplying this board with? What is the current draw of the cooling pad?

Comment: Looks to me like your cooling pad is drawing more current than you can supply

Comment: Please provide details of how much current the cooler takes. Do you understand why I am asking this? Without this figure it's impossible to select a voltage converter because, you won't know what current it needs to deliver to the cooler. You also need to determine how much current the voltage converter can deliver before running out of steam. These details are crucial before you can choose/buy anything.

Comment: Two 12.5 cm fans side by side in a 10×5 cm² enclosure - *that*'s space efficient. No electrical specs at all? No bragging about efficiency - if that's linear regulators, you don't even have 400 mA@9 V when drawing max from 5 V&3.3 V - for CPU fan **+** cooling pad.

Comment: @Puffafish
I just checked the current drawn on my cooling pad using multimer, it is drawing around 620mA when running on 5V Mobile phone adapter.

Comment: Those are 1117s on the board--linear regulators. They're going to get *hot* if you try to power a high-current load like that cooling pad from them.

Comment: Sounds like you're drawing too current. What are you powering the power board with?

Comment: @Puffafish I am either using 9V 2A OR 12V 2A Adapter, but result is same in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

It's supposed to work that way.

The regulator overheats from too much load and thermal shutdown activates to protect from further damage.

Even at 9V in, the 0.6A load requires the 5V regulator to dissipate 2.4 watts.

The AMS1117 regulator datasheet says that if the PCB has poor thermal conductivity, the regulator temperature might rise 120 °C per watt, and thus can't even handle 1 watt.

Comment: Is there any such module available online which can fulfill my requirement of powering all 3 loads? Or any better module which can provide more than 3 outputs? pls provide the link of any such module if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Requesting suggestions what to buy is off-topic. However, your original question why the module does not power your loads is now answered.